# Conditional WHERE clause with case statement

Tags: sql

I am working with the following query and I'm stuck

```
SELECT 
    @siteID = Site.siteID, 
    @customerID = Customer.customerID 
FROM 
    Customer
    inner join Site on Customer.siteID = Site.siteID
WHERE 
    Site.phoneNumber = @vaultID 
    and Customer.clientID = @clientID
```

Some of the Customer.clientID fields are being updated from a four character field to an eight character field, ex: '1234' is becoming '1234  01'.  The customer will always be passing in a four character ID.  Depending on what siteID they're record has, I need to modify the query so that it reads only the first four characters of the ID.  So what I have been trying to work on is adding this in the where clause:

```
    AND
CASE
    WHEN Site.siteID IN ('1T','1Q') 
    THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Customer.clientID ,1,6)))= @clientID
ELSE
    Customer.clientID = @clientID
END
```

but I'm not having much luck.  The research I've done so far leads me to believe case statements in the where clause aren't a great idea to begin with but I feel like I'm close here.  I know I can make a totally separate call to the site table before making this call but I really want to get this in one statement, hoping that's possbile.

Comment: why not use dynamic SQL....

Comment: Dynamic SQL is forbidden here I'm afraid.  That's the way I would have preferred to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case statement should look like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN Site.siteID IN ('1T','1Q') 
    THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Customer.clientID ,1,6)))
  ELSE Customer.clientID
END = @clientID
```

You don't do comparisson inside the CASE, rather use the CASE to get you the value which you can compare.

Comment: That is so frustrating, I keep forgetting that detail and it's a big one.  Thank you Tom, huge help.